I am having an issue with running wpscan on macOS using homebrew: I keep getting an issue with nokogiri and a bundler issue
I keep getting this error:
Last 15 lines from /Users/christos/Library/Logs/Homebrew/wpscan/02.bundle: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/wpscan/3.8.25/libexec/gems/bundler-2.5.14/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in block in process_queue'
internal:kernel:187:in loop' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/wpscan/3.8.25/libexec/gems/bundler-2.5.14/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in process_queue'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wpscan/3.8.25/libexec/gems/bundler-2.5.14/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in
`block (2 levels) in create_threads'
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.15.6), and Bundler cannot
continue.
In Gemfile:
wpscan was resolved to 3.8.25, which depends on
cms_scanner was resolved to 0.13.9, which depends on
nokogiri
I cannot seem to figure out what to do here. I am new to bash commands and I am trying to understand why I keep getting this issue and what it means.
`
I tried to re-run the command: brew install wpscanteam/tap/wpscan

I solved the issue here. Just made sure that I was up to date and then ran: brew reinstall wpscan

What do you mean by up to date @Christos?

@JTX I meant the latest version
